# Weight doubled for configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, orders, simple-product, magento-1.9.3.8, product-weight

I have created a **configurable product** with a simple product as child (in **Magento 1.9.3.8**). The simple product has been given a weight of **100 kg**.

When buying the **simple product** by directly browsing to it, not by selecting it from the configurable, the weight is **calculated correctly** for the order (100 kg).

When buying the same product by browsing to the **configurable** and choosing it via a drop-down, the weight for the order is **doubled (200 kg)**. If I buy two of the simple product this way the weight ends up at 400 kg.

I can see Magento has set these incorrect weights for the order in **`sales_flat_order`** so it's not a presentation issue.

As we display the weight in our admin's order overview prior to selecting appropriate shipping this causes problems.

Have I set this up incorrectly? Why Magento is calculating weight differently based on if I add the product as **simple** or **configurable**? Is there a **`non-hacky`** way to have magento calculate order weight solely based on the **simple products** total weight and not double it for **configurable**?

Comment: Did you set weight for configurable products?

Comment: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php#L773-L792

Comment: No, @SukumarGorai, the configurable product does not even have a weight attribute.

Comment: @B00MER, that code snippet doesn't tell me why the configurable is given twice the weight. Or am I missing something?